# How to get width of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I used the class css `text-overflow: ellipsis;` , but I need to get the width of the div parent `id="container"` , and the width of the div child `class="ellipsis"` would be the same value as the parent div .

```
<div id="container" >
          <div class="title" >
            title
            <div class="actions-container" >
              <div class="fields">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div  class="body"  >

            <div class="champ2">
            Paragraphe :
            </div>
            <div  class="valeur"  >
              <div class="ellipsis" appIsEllipsisActiveDirective  >
                Un paragraphe est une section de texte en prose vouée au développement d'un point particulier souvent au moyen de plusieurs phrases, dans la continuité du précédent et du suivant. Sur le plan typographique, le début d'un paragraphe est marqué par un léger renfoncement ou par un saut de ligne
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. The question is really vague. Please take a moment and read [ask] and edit your question with [mcve] of your code and explain in detail what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: To find the width: document.getElementById('elementId').offsetWidth, To get the parent element: document.getElementById("elementId").parentElement.nodeName. By using these two lines your problem can be solved and if you want the exact answer then please add your code here.

Comment: @4LPH4 , I add the code in the description .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set in the style of the child div width: 100%; or try margin-right: 0px;